# Check date value in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

IN Netezza , I am trying to check if date value is valid or not ; something like ISDATE function in SQL server.

I am getting dates like 11/31/2013 which is not valid, how in Netezza I can check if this date is valid so I exclude them from my process.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a built-in Netezza function to check if a date is valid. You may be able to write a LUA function to do this, or you could try joining to a "Date" lookup table, like so:

Create a table with two columns:

```
DATE_VALUE date
DATE_STRING varchar(10)
```

Load data into this table for valid dates (generate a file in your favorite tool, excel, unix, whatever). There can even be more than one row per DATE_VALUE (different "valid" formats) if all you use this for is this check. If you fill in from, say, 1900 to 2100, as long as your data is within that range, you'll be fine. And it's a small table, too, for ~200 years only ~7300 rows. Add more if needed. Heck, since the NZ date datatype goes from AD1 to AD 9999, you could fill it completely with only 3.4 million rows (small for NZ).

Then, to isolate rows that have invalid dates, just use a `JOIN` or an `EXISTS` / `NOT EXISTS` to this table, on DATE_STRING. Since the table is so small, netezza will likely broadcast it to all SPUs, making the performance impact trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Netezza Analytics Package 3.0 (free download) comes with a couple LUA functions that verify date values:  isdate() and todate().  Very simple to install / compile.